# Cocoapod CI on travis can't install dependencies

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, travis-ci

This is a cocoapod I created with `pod lib create` according to the cocoapods guide: https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html. The directory stucture and files and the example project were generated for me.

My .travis.yml looks like this:

```
# references:
# * https://www.objc.io/issues/6-build-tools/travis-ci/
# * https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty#usage

osx_image: xcode10.3
language: objective-c
# cache: cocoapods
xcode_workspace: Example/MUXSDKImaListener.xcworkspace
xcode_scheme: MUXSDKImaListener-Example
podfile: Example/Podfile
xcode_sdk: iphonesimulator9.3
before_install:
- gem install cocoapods # Since Travis is not always on latest version
- pod repo update
- pod install --project-directory=Example
script:
- set -o pipefail && xctool test -enableCodeCoverage YES -workspace Example/MUXSDKImaListener.xcworkspace -scheme MUXSDKImaListener-Example -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO | xcpretty
- pod lib lint
```

When travis tries to build these tests, it runs into an error when installing Cocoapods. This output is a bit confusing because it seems to say it needs Mux-Stats-AVPlayer 1.0.1, but then it stays it can't find that version.

That version exists: https://cocoapods.org/pods/Mux-Stats-AVPlayer

```
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 2.0.2
announce
$ xcodebuild -version -sdk
$ pod --version
1.7.5
before_install.1
2.77s$ gem install cocoapods
2.76s$ pod install --repo-update --project-directory=Example
Updating local specs repositories
Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Mux-Stats-AVPlayer":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Mux-Stats-AVPlayer (= 1.0.1, ~> 1.0.1)
  In Podfile:
    Mux-Stats-Google-IMA (from `../`) was resolved to 0.3.0, which depends on
      Mux-Stats-AVPlayer (~> 1.0.1)
None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies: `Mux-Stats-AVPlayer (= 1.0.1, ~> 1.0.1), Mux-Stats-AVPlayer (~> 1.0.1)`.
You have either:
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.3` on target `MUXSDKImaListener_Tests` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
The command "pod install --repo-update --project-directory=Example" failed and exited with 31 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

The full build is here:

https://travis-ci.org/muxinc/mux-stats-google-ima/builds/588638291

It seems like I'm missing something obvious in this .travis.yml config file.

Podfile for the example project

```
use_frameworks!
target 'MUXSDKImaListener_Tests' do
  pod 'Mux-Stats-Google-IMA', :path => '../'

  pod 'Specta'
    pod 'Expecta'
end
```

Podfile.lock for Example project

```
PODS:
  - Expecta (1.0.6)
  - GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK (3.10.1)
  - Mux-Stats-AVPlayer (1.0.1):
    - Mux-Stats-Core (~> 2.0.0)
  - Mux-Stats-Core (2.0.12)
  - Mux-Stats-Google-IMA (0.3.0):
    - GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK (~> 3.9)
    - Mux-Stats-AVPlayer (~> 1.0.1)
  - Specta (1.0.7)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - Expecta
  - Mux-Stats-Google-IMA (from `../`)
  - Specta

SPEC REPOS:
  https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git:
    - Expecta
    - GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK
    - Mux-Stats-AVPlayer
    - Mux-Stats-Core
    - Specta

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  Mux-Stats-Google-IMA:
    :path: "../"

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Expecta: 3b6bd90a64b9a1dcb0b70aa0e10a7f8f631667d5
  GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK: 0e37ab83b22075ad631a70dcba9528cb246c92bf
  Mux-Stats-AVPlayer: e8ab70f9e67ac54958ac6ee87f479e3c0486baf5
  Mux-Stats-Core: 73e692799571459722526ff4a721b6872da5c776
  Mux-Stats-Google-IMA: 6ef4042dc3a1052ed55edfcc35a55b8106d2a4a3
  Specta: 3e1bd89c3517421982dc4d1c992503e48bd5fe66

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 95e48c48a4efb20f1822c750f01f9c105d46475a

COCOAPODS: 1.7.5
```

Mux-Stats-Google-IMA.podspec file for the pod:

```
#
# Be sure to run `pod lib lint MUXSDKImaListener.podspec' to ensure this is a
# valid spec before submitting.
#
# Any lines starting with a # are optional, but their use is encouraged
# To learn more about a Podspec see https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'Mux-Stats-Google-IMA'
  s.version          = '0.3.0'
  s.summary          = 'Mux-Stats-Google-IMA is for tracking performance analytics and QoS monitoring for video with mux.com.'

  s.description      = <<-DESC
    The Mux Stats Google IMA is designed to be used with Mux-Stats-AVPlayer and GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK to track performance analytics and QoS monitoring for video.
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://mux.com'
  s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/muxhq'
  s.license          = { :type => 'Apache 2.0', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Mux' => 'ios-sdk@mux.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/muxinc/mux-sdk-ima-listener.git', :tag => "v#{s.version}" }

  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'

  s.source_files = 'MUXSDKImaListener/Classes/**/*'

  s.dependency 'Mux-Stats-AVPlayer', '~> 1.0.1'
  s.dependency 'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.9'
end
```

Comment: And what does your `Podfile` say? There's where you define your dependencies and versions. Did you try using `~> 1.0`?

Comment: @AlejandroIván thanks! I added the Podfile for the example project which references the podspec in the parent directory (which I also added). I created this cocoapod with `pod lib create` according to the CocoaPods guide which lays out this stucture https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html

Comment: They look fine, sounds to me that you need to update the versions locked by your `Podfile.lock` file. Did you try running `pod update` instead of `pod install`? That should re-write your `Podfile.lock` using the versions specified in your `Podfile`. Pretty sure no pipeline should rely on `pod install` but rather on `pod update`, since version of libraries can change all the time and `pod install` prefers the lock file over the versions specified on the `Podfile` if it has to solve any conflicts.

Comment: @AlejandroIván yep! my Podfile.lock is updated for 1.0.1 (added that to my post too). And yes, I ran `pod update` so that the Podfile.lock got updated

Comment: Pretty weird error. It could be something when mixing local and remote pods. I would try adding 'Mux-Stats-AVPlayer', '~> 1.0.1'` to the Podfile to test what's going on. Sorry I can't help too much, Github was blocked at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the pod install in my example was failing, but reverting back to the auto-generated .travis.yml fixed it. The only thing I had to modify was adding a the instructions under `before_install:`

`pod setup` without this line - the `pod lib lint` failed with a specific error:

> ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to find a specification for `Mux-Stats-AVPlayer (~> 1.0.0)` depended upon by `Mux-Stats-Google-IMA`) during validation.

`gem update concurrent-ruby` without this line - the `pod lib lint` failed with a different error:

> ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (uninitialized constant Concurrent::Promises) during validation.

So, this is what my `.travis.yml` looks like now and it runs the tests and runs `pod lib lint`.

```
# references:
# * https://www.objc.io/issues/6-build-tools/travis-ci/
# * https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty#usage

osx_image: xcode7.3
language: objective-c
# cache: cocoapods
# podfile: Example/Podfile
before_install:
- gem install cocoapods # Since Travis is not always on latest version
# Avoid error: Encountered an unknown error (uninitialized constant Concurrent::Promises) during validation
# https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8948
- gem update concurrent-ruby
- pod setup
# - pod install --project-directory=Example
script:
- set -o pipefail && xcodebuild test -enableCodeCoverage YES -workspace Example/MUXSDKImaListener.xcworkspace -scheme MUXSDKImaListener-Example -sdk iphonesimulator9.3 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO | xcpretty
- pod lib lint
```